# Can writeSpatialShape save shapefile with projection (CRS)?

Tags: r, r-maptools

Can `writeSpatialShape { maptools }` be somehow forced to write the shapefile with CRS?

```
writeSpatialShape(socc_buf, "f:/hdf/socc_buff_R.shp") # no CRS in the shapefile
```

There does not seem to be an option for this.

PS: I know it can be done using `writeOGR { rgdal }`.

Comment: Unless something changed and I doubt, I think is not possible (source : Roger Bivand) https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2011-November/013568.html

Comment: Why don't you want to use `writeOGR` ?

Comment: @dickoa I am using it, I am just curious about writeSpatialShape. Thanks

Comment: a reason for not using writeOGR is, that it rediculously abbreviates your column names with shape files -> unusable for me when i mass-produce layers where I then have to restore the column names manually.
writeSpatialShape doesn't produce the .prj, but with that I can live. If only writeOGR for spatialite was able to add layers to an existing db, live would be perfect.

Comment: Thanks @BerndV. for pointing out the problem (here I found more information: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/30785), but according to the information given there this is not problem of `writeOGR`, but of the `dbf` format. If you don't agree please post followup comment [right there](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/35111/4630).

Comment: Its true that dbf accepts only 10 characters as field names. But writeOGR even cripples fields with only 7 or 8 or even less characters.(Example: "ora_nachwe" becomes "or_nch_" !  Thats why I can't use it to produce output I want to work with, but use writeSpatialShape now, where it is one click in QGIS to assign a projection, while with writeOGR I have to work 5 + minutes to restore fieldnames.

Answer (score 0):

TMS

You need to remove the .shp from the filename as it creates a .shp  .shx and .dbf file. According to the package manual "fn shapefile layer name, when writing omitting the extensions *.shp, *.shx and *.dbf, which are added in the function"

Thanks

tony.